# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 hangs when compiling in Release mode

Tags: c#, build, compilation, visual-studio-2015

I can successfully build my Solution in debug mode, but occasionally (about every 1 in 4) when I then try to build in Release mode, it just seems to stop.

The symptoms are that it "freezes" on a different project each time.  The time spent compiling counter keeps incrementing though (so I see a build process that normally takes 2 minutes is now well over 13 minutes, and counting.  If I click on another TAB, I sometimes get "Visual Studio is busy", but even that stops appearing after a while.

Running ProcMon and filtering to the relevant process ID, I see lots of entries along the lines of:

- **Operation**: QueryDirectory
- **Path**: C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\ApplicationInsights\vstelf144292e-e3b2-4011-ac90-20e5c03fbce5*.trn
- **Result**: NO SUCH FILE

The "vstelf...." directory is in fact empty when I look.

There are also occasional calls to

- **Operation**: QueryDirectory
- **Path**: C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\ApplicationInsights\vstelAIF-312cbd79-9dbb-4c48-a7da-3cc2a931cb70
- **Result**: NO MORE FILES

I got a dump file from TaskManager, but it was huge and when I tried to debug this using VisualStudio, it just gave me disassembly information.

Griff

Comment: Mines not :(  What happens if you disable your antivirus, does it quit it then?

Comment: Smells like Avast again.  Uninstall asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of desperation, I fixed this by uninstalling VS2015 Update 2, and all previous versions of VS (of which there were quite a few) and then re-installed VS2015 Update 2.

Comment: I have the ~same situation: it freezes build, on random project, time is ticking, no output, it happens every 2nd or 3rd time I start "Build solution" or "Start debug". What is different: I have this in Debug build. I had this before, can't recall how I solved (probably by reinstalling) but this time I know that it came back after installing Windows Performance Toolkit (Windows 8.1 SDK).  I'll follow your way to put it back.